# How can I erase lines with acclerometer?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, accelerometer

I need a short code for erasing lines drawn on an Android device. This is the code that generates my line:

```
this.graphics.lineTo(event.stageX, event.stageY);
```

I cannot seem to get the code right for erasing this line with movement detected by the accelerometer. I want to shake it like an 'etch-a-sketch' to erase the lines.

Is there anyone that can help me. This is all new to me.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
this.graphics.clear();
```

This will erase everything created by this.graphics (which is presumably what you want).